# Apache POI, Handling WorkbookFactory.create() exception for better user experience

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, exception, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI to parse and create excel files, I'm working on a base64 string (user excel input file content) and converting it to a ByteArrayInputStream :

`ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64String));`

and then creating a Workbook :

```
try (Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(stream)) {

  //parsing the file content ...

} catch (IOException e) {
   log.error("hopefully something clear", e);
   throw new CustomException(Errors.CUSTOM_ERROR_CODE_FOR_THIS_PARTICULAR_ISSUE);
}
```

The thing is, I don't know exactly why the create method threw the exception, the documentation just says

> Throws:
>       java.io.IOException - if an error occurs while reading the data 
>   [(link)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html#create-java.io.InputStream-)

And I don't want to show the user "There was an error while parsing the file", I've already handled the case if the file is encrypted but in this I'm stuck

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy actual error message from underlying exception:

   ```
    try (Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(stream)) {     
    //parsing the file content ...    
    } catch (IOException e) {
      log.error("hopefully something clear", e);
      throw new CustomException(e.getMessage(),
         Errors.CUSTOM_ERROR_CODE_FOR_THIS_PARTICULAR_ISSUE);
     }
   ```
2. For better user experience, you definitely need to handle cases with empty or broken data:

   ```
   final String base64String = .. ;
   //StringUtils class is from Apache Commons Lang
   if (StringUtils.isEmpty(base64String) {
      throw new CustomException(Errors.CUSTOM_ERROR_NO_DATA);
   }

   byte[] bytes;
   try {
     bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64String);
   } catch (Exception e) {
     throw new CustomException(Errors.CUSTOM_ERROR_NON_BASE64_DATA);
   }

   try (ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);) {
   .. // workbook processing 
   }
   ```